# Запуск консольных программ через Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

пытаюсь написать программу в Python3, которая будет использовать файл и запускать его в других программах. Трудность заключается в том, что другие программы имеют разные опции при запуске и аутпут первой используемой программы это инпут для второй.

Использую subprocess, но не совсем понимаю как сделать, чтобы аутпут первой был использован как инпут второй программы, учитывая, что инпут и аутпут это опции, которые задаются для запуска каждой программы.

Может быть есть какие-то другие способы кроме использования subprocess для этой задачи? Посоветуйте пожалуйста оптимальные варианты архитектуры для новой программы.

Answer (score 1):

Нет тут никакой трудности

```
list_dir = Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=PIPE)
count_lines = Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=list_dir.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
```